# Possible misalignment within mod message page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

It appears that various elements are misaligned within the mod message page:

[image: "Moderator private message" guidelines (1)]

---

[image: "Moderator private message" guidelines (2)]

I don't remember exactly how it used to look, but I believe the guidelines box (and the message box) should be along the left under the header with the chat boxes along the right.

- **OS:** Windows 7
- **Browser:** Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m
- **Active extensions:** None

Comment: Looks normal on maths. Are you running any browser extensions/user scripts?

Comment: None are active now.  Of course, it'll help if I include my specs.  I'm not sure how I forgot that.

Comment: Gonna take a look on it. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: @Paweł So, what did you find?

Comment: @Mast Still looking!